# Get the specific value data inside the arrays of nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays

Im new to Node js and I want to get the value of "dayname" inside the array

```
 [
 {
  dayname: '20',
  daynumber: 'TUESDAY',
  employee: 'Lily Rose Villarosa',
  id: '7497',
  month: 'October',
  time: '14:06',
  year: '2020'
},
{
 dayname: '20',
 daynumber: 'TUESDAY',
 employee: 'Lily Rose Villarosa',
 id: '7497',
 month: 'October',
 time: '16:18',
 year: '2020'
}
]
```

Above is the list of data inside my `var array=[]`

Now how can I get the value of `dayname` inside of each data

Im doing `array.dayname` but it say undefined

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your need for dayname is but this simple example should get you going in the right direction. there is better ways of doing this, this is just for understanding purposes...

```
 var myArray = [{
     dayname: '20',
     daynumber: 'TUESDAY',
     employee: 'Lily Rose Villarosa',
     id: '7497',
     month: 'October',
     time: '14:06',
     year: '2020'
   },
   {
     dayname: '20',
     daynumber: 'TUESDAY',
     employee: 'Lily Rose Villarosa',
     id: '7497',
     month: 'October',
     time: '16:18',
     year: '2020'
   }
 ]
```

you need to iterate(loop) over the array and then you can access the key(dayname) for each object.

```
 var dayname = null;
 myArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
   dayname = item.dayname;
   console.log(dayname);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let daynanes = []
array.forEach(el=>{
daynames.push(el.dayname)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array from array either using .Map or .Filter

for example,

```
var data=[{
    'a' : 'text'
},{
    'a' : 'text'
},{
    'a' : 'text'
}];
var new_array = data.map(function(element){
    return element['a'];
});
```

you can use filter as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a dayname directly, you can use "array[0].dayname". The Number indicates the index of the array.
If you want to get an array of daynames, the best approach would be the map function.

```
 let daynames = array.map(function(item){
  return item.dayname;
}
```